# Access(Visual Basic) What is better for perfomance? VBa Code or Macro

Tags: ms-access, vba

Well, the thing is: I have a button, and Im able to assign it to a Macro or to VBa code, but what would be better for optimization? The gain would be only superficial? Btw, I'm not using recorded macros.

Comment: Depends on the code your macro would use vs. the code in VBA. How do you generate your macro?

Comment: The macros are required to be created by recording, but I edit them to remove some unused stuff, like adding some With....End With, etc

Comment: But the macro in this case, it's executed by a click event of a button

Comment: A recorded (and altered) macro is exactly VBA code. Button or not, it only depends on the code itself. Can you test it by calling your macro xxx amount of times and compare it to calling your handwritten vba code xxx amount of times?

Comment: Performance: no difference. Maintainability: VBA wins. Use VBA. An `AutoExec` macro is usually the only one you need. BTW, Access doesn't even have a macro recorder (or do newer versions?).

Comment: It's not exactly a macro recorder, it's more of an assistant, but it generates some bad practice code

Comment: @DavidG yes, but the question was more for general purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, VBA code is compiled. So such code is faster. However if you not running much code, then no difference will be seen.

However if you execute a command in VBA to open a form, or execute a openform command via a macro, the VBA code executes likely 1000 times faster. However, both spend 99% of their time waiting for the SAME “openForm” command. So if you just launching a report, or opening some forms, then you not notice any difference in performance.

However, if you doing any number crunching or looping – then VBA will run MANY MANY times faster than macro code. So it really depends on the time spent “running” VBA code vs using built in Access objects. The access objects such as forms, reports, query etc. run identical in terms of performance. So for a few lines of code, you not notice the difference because the % time spent executing a few lines of code is so very small.

However, for a code heavy solution in which you execute lots of instructions or “lines” of code (such as looping, or iterative solutions)?

Then VBA will win hands down – it is several 1000 times faster executing macro code. VBA code does have a compiler – macro code does not and is interpreted.